# How to create schema binding and index on view from other server?

Tags: sql-server, optimization, indexing, view, schema

I have tried creating a view with the help of schema binding and indexing which is referring from other server table. But sql thrown some error for the below query .

```
 create VIEW [dbo].[Vxyz]
  with schemabinding
  AS 
  SELECT 
  ELID,USECOUNT,LASTUPDATE,TYPE,CODENE,CASNUE,NAME_ENG,ISGROUP,CHGROUP,DLink 
  IDE,LOCKBY,PhyApB,BUILDNO,PMNNumE,EINECE 
  FROM IADL.dbo.tblxyz 
  GO
  create unique clustered index IDX_xyz on [dbo]. 
  [Vxyz](ELID)
```

[image]
[image]

Found below error

> Msg 4512, Level 16, State 3, Procedure IADL.dbo.tblxyz, Line 3 [Batch Start Line 11]
>   Cannot schema bind view '[dbo].[Vxyz]' because name 'IADL.dbo.tblxyz' is invalid for schema binding. Names must be in two-part format 
>   and an object cannot reference itself.
>   Msg 1939, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
>   Cannot create index on view '[dbo].[Vxyz]' because the view is not schema bound.

```
 select distinct 
    ISNULL(A.elid, B.elid) ElementID, 
    CASE when A.elid is null and B.elid is not null then 'Missing ElementID :'+ 
        B.elid+' in Mainproductsall table' when A.elid is not null 
        and B.elid is null then 'Missing ElementID :'+ A.elid+' in Genproductsall table' Else 'OK' 
    end Datastatus 
into ABC 
from [dbo].[Vxyz] As A 
full outer join [dbo].[Vxyzwa] as B on A.elid = B.elid 
where A.elid is null or B.elid is null
```

Each from from above query is **view** . As per my first query above which is  referring from other server. so i want to optimize and i am trying to create index.

Comment: Please replace **picture of text** with text.

Comment: @IvanStarostin : replaced Thank you

Comment: This error message does not match given code

Comment: @IvanStarostin : sorry i have edited now.

Comment: One small comment, you wrote "referring from other server table". In fact you are referring from other database in the same SQL Server instance. If it was from another instance on the same server, then you should add the fourth idendifier which will form the Fully Qualified Name of Database Object http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/get-fully-qualified-name-using-sql-function.aspx . In fact there is a difference between server, instance, database, and also a relation.

Comment: @Eralper . Then to optimize the view when referring from other server table . because its taking too long to execute

Comment: What exactly _takes too long to execute_? Any select from this table? A particular query?

Comment: @IvanStarostin    select distinct ISNULL(A.elid, B.elid) ElementID,        
CASE when A.elid is null and B.elid is not null then        
'Missing ElementID :'+ B.elid+' in  Mainproductsall table'        
when A.elid is not null and B.elid is null then        
'Missing ElementID :'+ A.elid+' in  Genproductsall table'        
Else 'OK' end Datastatus        
into ABC       
from [dbo].[Vxyz] As A full outer join  [dbo].[Vxyzwa] as B on        
A.elid = B.elid        
where A.elid is null or  B.elid is null

Comment: @IvanStarostin : each from is a view that why i want to create index , but this view is created by the help of other server

Comment: Please add this query to your question and format it for readability. Actual execution plan would be very helpful.

Comment: @IvanStarostin . thank you added.

Comment: What is `Vxyzwa`? Can you share actual execution plan?

Comment: @IvanStarostin  :  Vxyzwa it is other View . i gave example of

Comment: Voting to close because you are not sharing essential information for resolving your issue.

Comment: @IvanStarostin : I am trying to share . is it via screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

If you check official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=aps-pdw-2016), you will see that it is stated as follows

**All referenced objects must be in the same database.**

So you cannot refer a base table from an other database.

This means, for all referenced current database objects should be referenced with their schema name and object name.

Comment: To create the index on the view, the view must be "schema bound" . Since we cannot create the view with a schema binding table from another database, we cannot create the index too.

Comment: Then to optimize the view when referring from other server table . because its taking too long to execute